# PHP+AJAX (jQuery) - Reading session data on $.post() return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am currently writing an "Edit Account" module. Using jQuery.post(); I can successfully update my database, and I can write to the session variables from the PHP script - however,
when trying to access the Session variable that I just wrote to, the data does not seem to have been updated.

I write to the session like this: `$_SESSION['email'] = 'john@doe.com';` in my Ajax.php

My jQuery (minified) callback on success:

```
$.post(...,function(res)
{
  if(res=='success')
  {
    // Alert the new E-Mail, read from the Session!
    alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>"); 
  }
}
```

However, the alert does not output `john@doe.com`, it outputs whatever the E-Mail was it was when the **entire page was loaded**. When I refresh the page, the session data has been properly updated.

I do have `session_start();` on both index.php (my site) and in Ajax.php

If you need more info please do let me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it should be

`alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>");`

and secondly $.post is dynamic but `<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>` is static. It renders once, on load, not everytime you make an .post() so if

`$_SESSION['email'] = 'blah';` by the time the page is loaded, the alert will always be  `alert("blah");` , until you reload the page.

If you want to alert the new session variable you have to make a new ajax request to a php file (ie. return_session.php?key=email ), that will return the new session variable

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the alert string is generated when the page is loaded. And when you make an ajax request it still doesnt change, because its not refreshed. 
On ajax success you should output the responseText and then it will work.